# Kendo Grid Cell Templates

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, css-position, right-to-left

I need to add a checkbox and a circle to every cells of Kendo Grid. According to position attribute of Kendo grid cells, the result won't be aligned. Here is the result:

[image]

I'm using RTL version of Kendo grid.

Consider that I can't change the position attribute of Kendo grid cell because if I do so, when I click on each cell, the scroll will jump abnormally.

Comment: We need to see your template to see how those circles are being generated, css and stuff...

Comment: `template: function(data){
    return '<input type="checkbox"> ${data.value} <div class="circle">'
}`

Comment: Add any update to the question body. Also, add the related css if possible.

Comment: I didn't change any CSS style, I've used materialize framework + Kendo Grid.

Comment: thanks i solved this problem
i searched for this problem and i found that kendo have bug in rtl version